# JFace Dialog with Swing component

Tags: java, swing, swt

Is there a way to add Swing (`javax.swing.*`) component in Dialog (`org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog`) ?

I tried doing it with [SWT/AWT Bridge](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Swing-SWT-Integration/index.html) but since *parent* in `Composite` constructor must be also `Composite` it seems to me to be impossible.
Am I right? Or is there any other way to do that?

If yes, I would be very grateful for an working example.

Comment: It is described right there in the article you linked to: `Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.EMBEDDED | SWT.NO_BACKGROUND);
    Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(composite);`

Comment: No.  it is quiet possible to use swing over Jface/swt dialog.
It is a very bad idea to use Swing over swt /jface dialogue as certain limitations are there. http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Swing-SWT-Integration/index.html

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann, note that parent in your example is Composite not a Dialog...

Comment: @ArdeshanaMilan, you answer 'no' and 'it is quiet possible to use swing over dialog' at the same moment, so what is your answer finally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a composite inside your dialog and use that composite to build your swing component inside it.
inside your `createDialogArea(Composite parent)` method of your jface dialog:

```
Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.EMBEDDED);
```

( It needs to be `SWT.EMBEDDED` )
use this composite to build your frame :

```
Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(composite);
```

Use the frame to build swing components.

Comment: Thanks, but what about `Composite composite = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent)` in createDialogArea method, which is recommended I think ?

Comment: You'll need to place another Composite (with `SWT.EMBEDDED`) within the returned composite. You can set a `FillLayout` to the returned Composite to let the inner Composite take up the whole space.